# What are the uses of IDs in wxpython example wx.ID_EXIT

Tags: wxpython

I am doing a lesson in wxpython with zetcode. I'd like to know what are the uses of id. example wx.ID_EXIT. the tutorial says "The standard id will automatically add an icon and a shortcut" but i cant see any icons when i run the program. I'm using windows 7 btw.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 may not have a default exit icon or it may not be active in the theme that is currently in use. You should try cycling through the themes on your machine and see if you get an icon in any of them. I created the following simple example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        exit_btn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_EXIT)



########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="IDs")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

On Windows 7, I don't get an icon either. But if I run this code on Xubuntu, I get the following:

[image]

Comment: Adding the icon for stock IDs is dependent on if that is a normal behavior for the platform and/or the active theme and also on the type of widget where it is used.  For example in some cases you may get icons added to menu items, and not buttons. In other cases you may get both or neither.

Comment: I figured it was something along those lines.